# Rails 3 routing constraint based on format and subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

Here is my scenario

- I have a bottle model which is routed as a resource
- I have a subdomain "foo"

My requirement is the following

- A request to the /bottles/*whatever with "www" or no subdomain, made via html format should be redirected to `/bottles/*whateve`r to the "sub" subdomain
- A request to `/bottles/*whatever` with "foo" subdomain made via html format should just go straight to /bottles/*whatever without any redirection
- Any request to `/bottles/*whatever` with "www" or no subdomain made via json format shoudl go straight to /bottles/*whatever without any redirection
- A request to `/bottles/*whatever` with "foo" subdomain made via json format should just go straight to /bottles/*whatever without any redirection

Here is my routes.rb

```
scope :constraints => lambda{|req| ((req.subdomain =="" || req.subdomain=="www") && req.format == "html") } do
    match "/bottles/*whatever" => redirect{|p,req| URI.parse(req.url).tap { |x| x.host = "foo.#{x.host}" }.to_s}
    match "/bottles/" => redirect{|p,req| URI.parse(req.url).tap { |x| x.host = "foo.#{x.host}" }.to_s} 
  end

resources :bottles
```

the redirection part is constrained to make sure that we only redirect if we have "" or "Www" subdomain and format is html, otherwise directly use `resources :bottles`.

The above works perfectly in the below cases

- `me.com/bottles/*whatever with` html is redirected to `sub.me.com/bottles/*whatever`
- `sub.me.com/bottles/*whatever` with html directly routed to `sub.me.com/bottles/*whatever`
- `sub.me.com/bottles/*whatever` with json directly routed to `sub.me.com/bottles/*whatever`

but it fails in the following case

- `me.com/bottles/*whatever` with `json` is not redirected as expected but it messes up my `params`, `/bottles/1` should be matched with `resource :bottles` and take me to `bottles#show` with `params[:id]=1`, but it takes me to `bottles#show` with `params[:whatver] = 1`,why does it put my `id` param in the `whatever` field ? when it was never redirected and never matched the routes inside the constraint part.. Any Ideas, Some server logs below

  Started GET "/bottles/1.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-18 15:55:49 +0500
  Processing by BottlesController#show as JSON
    Parameters: {"whatever"=>"1"}
  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Bottle without an ID):
    app/controllers/bottles_controller.rb:16:in `show'